# PayPal Express Checkout: Billing Agreement Shipping Address and Payment Method Display

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Does the billing agreement acceptance page support displaying shipping address and payment method? So far I've been unable to induce this behavior. Nor have I found documentation which states if this is or is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time and effort, PayPal tech support finally provided an answer. Turns out the AMT parameter for SetExpressCheckout is responsible for the display of the address and payment controls on the billing agreement page. Passing AMT=0 will hide the controls and a value greater than 0 will unhide the controls.